# Sequência de caracteres com String.fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript

O seguinte script encontrado aqui no Stack imprime de "aaa" a "zzz" através do incremento de letras em ordem, uma a uma:

```
var str= 'aaa',
s= str;

while(str!=='zzz') {
  str= ((parseInt(str, 36)+1).toString(36)).replace(/0/g,'a');
  s+= '<br/> '+str;
}

document.body.innerHTML= s;
```

Saída:

```
aaa
aab
aac
...
aba
abb
abc
...
zzy
zzz
```

Meu intuito é continuar essa lógica, porém incluindo caracteres especiais, utilizando `String.fromCharCode()` do índice 33 ao 126.

Esse intervalo numérico já inclui todos os caracteres especiais, letras e números.

> A saída desejada deverá conter 16 caracteres, e não somente os três
>   acima.

Qual modificações seriam necessárias no script para realizar essa tarefa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na teoria o código vai resolver seu problema, utilizei a variável "n" como um ponteiro para saber qual posição do array deveria incrementar, porem acredito que na pratica vai demorar muitoooooooo a execução deste script independente do meio a ser utilizado.

```js
var v = [33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33];
var result = [];
var n = 15;
result.push(String.fromCharCode(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10],v[11],v[12],v[13],v[14],v[15]));

while (v[n] != 126 || n != 0) {
  if (v[n] == 126 && n != 0){
    v[n] = 33;
    n--;
  }
  else {
    if (v[n] != 126) {
      v[n]++;
      result.push(String.fromCharCode(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10],v[11],v[12],v[13],v[14],v[15]));
      n = 15;
    }
    else {
      result.push(String.fromCharCode(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10],v[11],v[12],v[13],v[14],v[15]));
    }
  }
};

var retorno = result.join('<br/>');
```

Comment: Vou testar assim que possível e dou um feedback. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples nesse caso é fazeres três ciclos `for` encadeados, porém devido ao grande número de resultados (1 092 727) tornar-se-à um pouco lento... no teste que fiz demorou 28,75s

```js
var str='';
s= str;

for(i=33;i<=126;i++)
  for(j=33;j<=126;j++)
    for(k=33;k<=126;k++)
      str+=String.fromCharCode(i)+String.fromCharCode(j)+String.fromCharCode(k)+' <br/> ';

document.body.innerHTML= str;
```

Saída:

```
!!!
!!"
!!# 
...
"<@|
<@}
<@~
"
```

Comment: No caso eu precisaria de uma saída com 16 caracteres... Seriam 16 loops for... Há outro jeito? Vou adicionar esse dado à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isto que você precisa, recomendo utilizar "String.fromCharCode".

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
var s = [];
var retorno = '';

for (c3 = 33; c3 < 126; c3++)
   for (c2 = 33; c2 < 126; c2++)
      for (c1 = 33; c1 < 126; c1++)
         s.push(String.fromCharCode(c1,c2,c3));
      
retorno = s.join('<br/>');
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: No caso eu precisaria de uma saída com 16 caracteres... Seriam 16 loops for... Há outro jeito? Vou adicionar esse dado à pergunta.